# Pierdo el valor en Angular5

Tags: angular

Tengo un Array que recoge un listado. Si hago un `console.log (this);`
Puedo ver en la consola el array con los elementos.

Pero si hago el `console.log(this.People);` me dice que es indefinido.

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Person } from '../class/personClass';
import { ConexionPersonService } from '../conexion-person.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-detail-user',
    templateUrl: './detail-user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./detail-user.component.css']
})
export class DetailUserComponent implements OnInit {

    detailPerson: Person;
    People:Person[];
    @Input() id;


    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private conexion: ConexionPersonService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.getPeople();
        this.getPerson();
    }

    getPeople(): void {
        //Aquí obtengo el array de People
        this.conexion.getPeople()
            .subscribe(People => this.People = People);
    }

    getPerson(): void {
        console.log ( "this en getPerson" , this); //Aquí se ven los datos
        console.log ( "persona en getPerson" , this.People); //Ya no
        console.log ( "id en getPerson" , this.id);
         this.detailPerson = this.conexion.getPerson(this.People,this.id);

     }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un problema con lo que se refiere `this` dentro del `subscribe(People => this.People = People)` ya que ese `this` no se refiere al que tu estas esperando.

Una solución fácil es crear otra variable, comúnmente llamada `that` la cual hace referencia a la propiedad `People` de tu clase:

```
getPeople(): void {
  //Aquí obtengo el array de People
  const that = this
  this.conexion.getPeople()
    .subscribe(People => that.People = People);
}
```

Te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://medium.com/entendiendo-javascript/entendiendo-this-javascript-cba60c8cec8c) sobre `this` en JavaScript el cual te puede resolver muchas dudas ya que este es de los principales problemas con los que se enfrentan los desarrolladores de JavaScript

Comment: Si todavía no funciona, el problema debe de ser que `getPeople()` no ha guardado el valor de `People` todavia cuando llamas `getPerson()` asegurate que termine la primer llamada antes de ejecutar `getPerson()`

Comment: Usa funciones flecha, eso mantiene el `this`. Creo que el problema es que llama a `getPerson()` demasiado pronto

Comment: @PabloLozano concuerdo contigo, debería de usar funciones flecha, sin embargo creo que es básico que todos los que desarrollamos en JavaScript entendamos perfectamente que es el scope de los objetos

Comment: Digo que **ya** está usándolas, que el problema no es ese.

Comment: Declarando that arriba y con this.that.People ya es accesible el array, gracias a los 2.

Comment: Ayudarme con https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154621/sacar-objeto-del-this-angular5 por favor , es referente a esto...

Answer (score -1):

Llamas a `this.getPerson()` demasiado rápido, antes de que la llamada a `this.getPeople()` se haya resuelto.

Tu código debería ser así:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-detail-user',
    templateUrl: './detail-user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./detail-user.component.css']
})
export class DetailUserComponent implements OnInit {

    detailPerson: Person;
    People:Person[];
    @Input() id;


    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private conexion: ConexionPersonService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.getPeople();
        // this.getPerson();
    }

    getPeople(): void {
        //Aquí obtengo el array de People
        this.conexion.getPeople()
            .subscribe(People => {
               this.People = People;
               this.getPerson(); //ahora this.People no es undefined
            });
    }

    getPerson(): void {
        console.log ( "this en getPerson" , this); //Aquí se ven los datos
        console.log ( "persona en getPerson" , this.People); //Ya no
        console.log ( "id en getPerson" , this.id);
         this.detailPerson = this.conexion.getPerson(this.People,this.id);

     }

}
```